# Angular 2 GET operation

Tags: angular

My header has a search form. Whenever that form is submitted, I will redirect to another URL like so:

```js
private onSubmit(){
    var url = './search/' + this.searchForm.get("query").value;
    this.router.navigate([url]);
  }
```

Now I am on the Search Result Page and everything works fine. But if I use the search form in the header again from the Search Result Page, nothing changes. I had to change the code where the search results are loaded from ngOnInit to ngDoCheck.

```js
ngDoCheck()
  {
    var query;

    this.route.params.forEach(params => 
    {
      query = params['query'];
    });

    this.items = this.itemService.searchItems(query);
  }
```

My goal is just to have a search form at the top of my website that will take me to a result page and show me the results. Just like any old GET form and some server side code would do it. What would be a sensible way of achieving this in Angular 2?

Comment: Just a note, idk about others, but seeing javascript formatted like its C just hurts my soul and makes it difficult to even pay attention to what's being asked. Could be just me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have to use the observable to listen to the changes in the serachbar use some observable to listen chnages in the search bar which fire event on button click or entry or whatever you like.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
.....


AbcObs: Rx.Subject<any> = new Rx.Subject<any>();
ABC: number = 0;


In your file where you want to show results
this.base_path_Service.ABcObs.subscribe(res => {
    // LISTEN TO CHANGES HERE AND FIRE SOME METHOD / EVENT AS PER REQUIREMENT
    //  here `base_path_Service` is some global service for the app
     this.onSubmit()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Routes have a lot of stuff built in. One of which is to see what route you currently are on.

What I would have done in your situation is to check the "current route". If you're not on the "search-route" (/search/), navigate to that page with the search data (as you're doing right now). Create a variable in which you store the search-data.

If you already are on the search page, you shouldn't navigate to the "search-route" you should only, on submit, update the variable you created before with the new search-data. If this variable is data-binded, everything should update automatically.

Pseudo code:

```
  private onSubmit(){
    if(/* NOT ON SEARCH-ROUTE */){
         var url = './search/' + this.searchForm.get("query").value;
         this.router.navigate([url]);
    }else{
         /* Update the variable on the search-page that holds the search-data */
    }
  }
```

I hope this is of any help.